# Как сконвертировать java.lang.Object to google.protobuf.Any?

Tags: grpc, google-protobuf

Метод Any.pack() умеет преобразовывать в Any только com.google.protobuf.Message, ниже его сигнатура.

```
public static <T extends com.google.protobuf.Message> Any pack(
      T message) {}
```

Но мне нужно сконвертировать любой java тип/класс в google.protobuf.Any.

Например, у меня есть следующий реквест с мапой:

```
message MetaRequest {
  map<string, google.protobuf.Any> params = 1;
}
```

И мне нужно отправить на эндпоинт соответствующий реквест с мапой Map<String, Object>, и нужно преобразовать его в Map<String, Any>.

Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса [нажав править ниже текста вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1529475/edit) на русский язык

Comment: Значит придётся дополнительно конвертировать `Object` в `c.g.p.Message`